# Comparing to void pointers whose actual type is known

Tags: c, pointers, types, mpi

I'm a bit lost on how to do the following:

```
void myMethod(void *ary, void *b, MPI_Datatype type) {

   if(ary[0] != b) { 
        /* do something */
   }
```

}

`b` is of type `type`, `ary` is an array of `type`. (The void pointers are used to enable the caller to pass elements of any kind of `MPI_Datatype`). How do I compare an element of `ary` with `b`?

I tried a view things but am stuck with the following error (using `mpicc -ansi -std=c99 -Wall -g -c):

```
warning: dereferencing `void *` pointer [enabled by default]
error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
```

EDIT: I fixed the typo in the function head: tpye -> type. I hope it didn't cause to much confusion

Comment: What if you try and cast `ary` first?

Comment: Did you mean "`b` is a pointer to `type`"? Otherwise how are you calling this function; by casting a `type` to a `void *`?

Comment: @Mr Lister: yes, that's right

Comment: Ignoring that there's a deferenced void pointer (`ary[0]`), am I missing something or are you trying to compare a type (in this case `void`) to a pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a type as a function parameter in C.

MPI uses values of type `MPI_Datatype` to indicate what type is being passed, but as far as C code is concerned, anything you write to actually do anything with an object needs to treat that object as having an actual type, known at compile time.

So, MPI probably provides you with some functions that help a bit (janneb points out `MPI_Type_size`, and I don't know what others there are). But for this kind of thing in C, you often end up having to laboriously write out code for each type:

```
switch(type) {
    MPI_LONG_DOUBLE:
        /* having said this, equality checks on floating-point types
           are often a mistake anyway due to rounding errors making
           values come out non-equal when "really" they're equal for
           your purposes. But that's a whole subject of its own.
        */
        if (*(long double*)ary != *(long double*)b) /* do something */;
        break;
    MPI_DOUBLE:
        if (*(double*)ary != *(double*)b) /* do something */;
        break;
    MPI_FLOAT:
        if (*(float*)ary != *(float*)b) /* do something */;
        break;
    MPI_INT:
        if (*(int*)ary != *(int*)b) /* do something */;
        break;
    /* etc ... */
    MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR:
        if (*(unsigned char*)ary != *(unsigned char*)b) /* do something */;
        break;
    default:
        /* janneb's code */
        int sz;
        MPI_Type_size(type, &sz);
        if (memcmp(ary, b, sz) {
            // do something
        }
        /* or it might be better to indicate an error, so that any types
           you haven't dealt with explicitly can be added to the code
           when encountered.
        */
}
```

Actually, janneb's code will work for all integer types on pretty much any C implementation you care to name, but if you care about "proper" portability you should probably treat them specially anyway.

Obviously you wouldn't really want to duplicate `/* do something */` in your code, so you'd probably define a function `equals`, and call that from the `if` test in `myMethod`.

Answer (score 3):

Dereferencing a `void*` is not allowed through either a `*` on an offset `[]`.  You need to convert them to the appropriate type via a cast before you can dereference.

```
void myMethod(void *ary, void *b, MPI_Datatype tpye) {

  type* aryType = ary;
  type* bType = b;
  if (aryType[0] != *bType) {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Now I get the following error: error: ‘aryType’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: @mort are you sure `type` is defined?

Comment: Yes, it's in the functions argument list

Comment: @Mort: you cannot pass a type to a function as a parameter in C. Your parameter is named `tpye`, not `type`, and it is a value of type `MPI_Datatype`, it is not a type.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: how is the example of JaredPar supposed to work then?

Comment: @mort: your question said that `ary` is an array of `type`. So JaredPar (reasonably, I think) assumed that you actually have a type named `type` in scope. Based on what you've since said, I don't think that assumption was correct, so this code will not work for you. Perhaps you should ask a question about what you actually want to do, instead of about how to implement the solution you've come up with, that's impossible in C because it seems to involve passing a type as a function parameter.

Comment: Or possibly this is really a question about MPI (specifically, how to recover the value given a `void*` and the MPI_Datatype value indicating its original type) rather than a question about C in general. Not knowing MPI, I don't really know whether the answer should involve writing some code that actually does it, or should involve calling a function that's part of the MPI interface.

Comment: @SteveJessop: No, there is no such function in MPI. OTOH, there is MPI_Type_size() which can be used to get the sizeof() of an element as specified by the accompanying MPI_Datatype value. Depending on what the OP wants to do, that may be enough in this case. For a simple example, see my answer..

Comment: @Steve Jessop: You actually answered my question. Would you like to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot dereference pointers to `void`, cast them to the appropriate type first:

```
((type *) ary)[0] != (type) b
```

For example, if your `type` is a pointer to `char *`, you would do:

```
((char **) ary)[0] != (char *) b
```

Comment: Well, the OP said `ary is an array of type`

Comment: @ouah: using (char **) and (char *) works for me, but using (type *) and (type) I get a rather strange error: 
error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
error: expected ‘)’ before ‘b’

Comment: @mort What do you use for `type`? I hope you understand you cannot use your parameter name you called `type` (`tpye` with the typo)?

Comment: @ouah: that's exactly what I was trying to do...thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to dereference void pointers.

If the point of the function is to compare a and b without the type being known as a type in C (which a MPI_Datatype value isn't), you can use memcmp():

```
void myMethod(void *ary, void *b, MPI_Datatype type)
{
    int sz;
    MPI_Type_size(type, &sz);
    if (memcmp(ary, b, sz) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this work? The man page of memcpy only states "The memcpy() function returns a pointer to dest."

Comment: @mort: My example doesn't use memcpy(), so I don't see how your comment is relevant.

Comment: This may be the closest you can get, but beware that in C it isn't always true that for `a` and `b` of the same type, `a == b` if and only if `memcmp(&a,&b,sizeof(a)) == 0`. Consider floating-point types, for example: negative `0` is equal to `0` despite having different bit patterns, and `NaN != NaN` even with the same bit pattern! On (very) uncommon architectures you can get similar things even with integer types: negative zeroes and padding bits, although for integer types if the bits are equal then the values are equal, always, provided you have valid values of the type.

Comment: Is it possible in MPI to write something along the lines of (made-up code): `if (MPI_Datatype == MPI_float) return *(float*)ary == *(float*)b; else if (MPI_Dataype == MPI_double) return *(double*)ary == *(double*)b) else if .... else return !memcmp(ary, b, sz);`?

Answer (score 1):

cast it to the type you know it is, or do the indexing yourself.

`((myArrayType*)ary)[0] != b`

or `(char*)ary + (size_element_in_bytes * index ) != (char*)b`